# How to add workspace indicator in Unity/Metacity?

Tags: workspaces, metacity

Is there a way I can add workspace indicator in Unity/Metacity? I'm trying to find how to enable it using gconf-editor or gconftool-2 in a way similar to what's shown here

[image]
<sub>(source: [addictivetips.com](https://cloud.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/System-tray.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I know exactly what you are going for. I saw this in an article some time ago the link to which can be found at the bottom.

[image]

In 12.04, you can install that by running these codes in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:geod/ppa-geod
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-workspaces
```

Once installed search for it in the Unity dash and done. You may also need to add it to the list of start-up applications.

In 12.10 Quantal, you have to install the .deb file built for 12.04 Oneiric manually (as of January 2013, the PPA doesn't have a package for 12.10). The .deb file you can obtain from the aforementioned [Launchpad PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~geod/+archive/ppa-geod). Run these in terminal:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~geod/+archive/ppa-geod/+files/indicator-workspaces_0.6.4_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i indicator-workspaces_0.6.4_all.deb
```

---

Source: http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/05/10-useful-application-indicators-for.html